# Complete installation of web aplication with data base and IIS

Tags: asp.net, database, iis, installation, web-deployment

I have web form aplication in asp.net and i have to create (has to be easy to install)complex instalator, witch will install IIS server, deploy the app to it create a local database and sets everything up. So the user will just complete installation and then will just run the aplication with out and other setting(or as little as posible).
I have no idea what to use or if it is even posible. Coudl you help me with what to use and how to create such instalation?

Thanks.

Comment: What you are searching is WIX.
[See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878752/how-to-create-msi-installer-for-asp-net-core-application-using-wix-toolset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you could try to use some extenstion tool to achieve your requirement.
Like Professional edition of [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/).

It support:

[IIS web sites, app pools, web apps and virtual directories](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-iis.html)

[Install windows features without writing any scripting](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/windows-features.html)

Comment: Thanks Advaced Installer would be perfect but the SW maybe used in comercial use and Advanced Installer is really expensive. So i am trying to find cheap solution.