# How do I create a Windows installer for .net core web application that runs as a service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services

I'm trying to figure out how to create an installer for my project but I am having trouble finding any documentation on it. The project is a web app that is hosted as a service and I need the installer to install that service.

Here is my Program.cs file if that helps in any way.

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseKestrel();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            })
            .UseWindowsService();
}
```

I'm still new to .Net and C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878752/how-to-create-msi-installer-for-asp-net-core-application-using-wix-toolset

Comment: How would I do this using the VS 2019 installer extension?